# Lodash merge: only copy object properties if source value matches destination value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, merge, lodash

I have two deep/complex objects being merged together.  In the 'addresses' array there needs to be two objects for two different address types, "PRIMARY" and "MAILING."

In my destination object, "PRIMARY" obj is above the "MAILING" obj.  Everything works great except for when there is only a "MAILING" obj available in the source object. When this occurs, both objects 'addressType' property are overwritten with "MAILING"

```
// In destination obj:
addresses: [
 {
  addressType: "PRIMARY",
  addressLine1: "",
  addressLine2: "",
  city: "",
  state: "",
  zip: ""
 },
 {
  addressType: "MAILING",
  ...
 }
]

// In source obj:
addresses: [
 {
  addressType: "MAILING",
  addressLine1: "123 Main St",
  addressLine2: "",
  city: "Hawkins",
  state: "IN",
  zip: "46001"
 }
]
```

After `merge` / Current Output (duplicate addressType):

```
_.merge({}, destination, source); //need new object

addresses: [
     {
      addressType: "MAILING",
      addressLine1: "123 Main St",
      addressLine2: "",
      city: "Hawkins",
      state: "IN",
      zip: "46001"
     },
     {
      addressType: "MAILING",
      addressLine1: "",
      addressLine2: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      zip: ""
     }
    ]
```

Desired Output:

```
// DESIRED OUTPUT:
addresses: [
     {
      addressType: "PRIMARY",
      addressLine1: "",
      addressLine2: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      zip: ""
     },
     {
      addressType: "MAILING",
      addressLine1: "123 Main St",
      addressLine2: "",
      city: "Hawkins",
      state: "IN",
      zip: "46001"
     }
    ]
```

The addresses array from the source may contain no objects, both, or one.

**So my question is,** if only "MAILING" comes in source obj, how do I prevent it from overwriting "PRIMARY" obj, leaving both a "MAILING" (from source) and "PRIMARY" obj (from destination)?

Should I be using mergeWith instead?

Comment: Could you write what array you've got?

Comment: @StepUp - Added what the current output is from the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get every scenario working using the following customizer function along with `mergeWith`:

```
mergeWith({}, destination, source, customizer);

const customizer = (objValue, srcValue, key) => {
  if (key === "addresses") {
    let merged = merge(
      keyBy(objValue, "addressType"),
      keyBy(srcValue, "addressType")
    );
    let value = values(merged);
    return value;
  }
};
```